# Extra field on Vaadin Login Screen for Spring Security

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Vaadin Flow V23.

I have created a custom filter and authentication service in Spring Security to add an extra field "domain" (source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields).  I need to pass the extra field from the Vaadin Login screen.  How do I customise the login component (source: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/tree/master/packages/login) into a custom login component in Vaadin?  I think I need to edit the Javascript and somehow integrate this into my project but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You cannot use the login component. You have to create your own login screen

Comment: This might help: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17959073/formsender-with-vaadinflow